# How to null check c# 7 tuple in LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-7.0

Given:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<(int a, int b, int c)> Map = new List<(int a, int b, int c)>()
    {
        (1, 1, 2),
        (1, 2, 3),
        (2, 2, 4)
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4);

        if (result == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Found");
    }
}
```

In the above example, a compiler error is encountered at line `if (result == null)`.

> CS0019    Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(int a, int b, int c)' and '<null>'

How would I go about checking that the tuple is found prior to proceeding in my "found" logic?

Prior to using the new c# 7 tuples, I would have this:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<Tuple<int, int, int>> Map = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>()
    {
        new Tuple<int, int, int> (1, 1, 2),
        new Tuple<int, int, int> (1, 2, 3),
        new Tuple<int, int, int> (2, 2, 4)
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Item1 == 4 && w.Item2 == 4);

        if (result == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Found");
    }
}
```

Which worked fine.  I like the more easily interpreted intention of the new syntax, but am unsure on how to null check it prior to acting on what was found (or not).

Comment: Value tuples are values types. They can't be null

Comment: In this case the default will be a tuple of 3 zeros instead of `null`.  So you could check for that instead.

Comment: @juharr but this will break if list contains (0,0,0) item, so not quite reliable.

Comment: @Evk (0,0,0) doesn't match the predicate in this case, but it could be an issue in other cases.

Comment: What is the compile error you get?

Comment: You're probably better off sticking with the reference `Tuple` type to differenciate between default and (0, 0, 0).  Also you can do `Tuple.Create(1, 1, 2)` instead of `new Tuple<int, int, int>(1, 1, 2)` to shorten that code a bit.

Comment: @juharr there is no reason to use the old Tuples. Just like there is no reason to cast an `int` to an `object` to check for a default value. You should compare with the correct *default*. That's what the method is supposed to return

Comment: @Kritner you should compare with the actual default for this type, ie `result.Equals(default(ValueTuple<int,int,int>))`. The use of `equals` stirps the name checks performed by the compiler and compares the tuple values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not true.  What if the colleciton contains (0,0,0) and the predicate matches it?  Then you have to either do an up front check with `Any` or xanatos's trick with `Take(1).ToArray()` to differentiate between not found and found, but just happens to match the default.

Comment: @juharr the method is `FirstOrDefault`. That's what it does. It's not a `Where()`. It works the same whether it's applied to a list of structs or a list of integers. BTW, even if the list contained Tuples, you could insert null values and get a null, or more likely, an exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not arguing over what the method does, just that when it returns the default value you don't know if it's because the first value was the default or if there was no matching first value.  And as you said in this case if there was a `null` in there the predicate would result in an exception (something that could be filtered out before hand if needed).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Value tuples are value types. They can't be null, which is why the compiler complains. The old Tuple type was a reference type

The result of `FirstOrDefault()` in this case will be a default instance of an `ValueTuple<int,int,int>` - all fields will be set to their default value, 0.

If you want to check for a default, you can compare the result with the default value of `ValueTuple<int,int,int>`,  eg:

```
var result=(new List<(int a, int b, int c)>()
            {
                (1, 1, 2),
                (1, 2, 3),
                (2, 2, 4)
            }
        ).FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4);

if (result.Equals(default(ValueTuple<int,int,int>)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing!"); 
}
```

**WORD OF WARNING**

The method is called `FirstOrDefault`, not `TryFirst`. It's not meant to check whether a value exists or not, although we all (ab)use it this way.

Creating such an extension method in C# isn't that difficult. The classic option is to use an out parameter:

```
public static bool TryFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq,Func<T,bool> filter, out T result) 
{
    result=default(T);
    foreach(var item in seq)
    {
        if (filter(item)) {
            result=item;
            return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling this can be simplified in C# 7 as :

```
if (myList.TryFirst(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 1,out var result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

F# developers can brag that they have a [Seq.tryPick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.trypick%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) that will return `None` if no match is found.

C# doesn't have Option types or the Maybe type (yet), but maybe (pun intended) we can build our own:

```
class Option<T> 
{
    public T Value {get;private set;}

    public bool HasValue {get;private set;}

    public Option(T value) { Value=value; HasValue=true;}    

    public static readonly Option<T> Empty=new Option<T>();

    private Option(){}

    public void Deconstruct(out bool hasValue,out T value)
    {
        hasValue=HasValue;
        value=Value;
    }
}

public static Option<T> TryPick<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq,Func<T,bool> filter) 
{
    foreach(var item in seq)
    {
        if (filter(item)) {
            return new Option<T>(item);
         }
    }
    return Option<T>.Empty;
}
```

Which allows writing the following Go-style call:

```
var (found,value) =myList.TryPick(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 1);
```

In addition to the more traditional :

```
var result=myList.TryPick(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 1);
if (result.HasValue) {...}
```

Comment: But the LINQ query posted would clearly not find a tuple in the list that has an `a` and `b` of 4, so how would I go about verifying that?

Comment: You'll get a default value back - a tuple with all fields set to defaults ie 0.

Comment: which could be a valid case in the `Map`, I'm not actually using several `int`s it was only meant as an example.

Comment: @Kritner what is the question then? `FirstOrDefault` returns either the first value, or a default value. Just as a `List<int>` would return 0 (default for ints), in this case you'll get a default struct, ie a ValueTuple with all fields set to default values

Comment: @Kritner With `First` you'll get an exception instead.  I would not recommend that if you know that the search might result in no results.

Comment: @Kritner You'd get an exception. If you want to check for a mismatch, you can actually compare with `default(ValueTuple<int,int,int>)`, eg `result.Equals(default(ValueTuple<int,int,int>))`

Comment: In C# 7.1 you can now just write: `if (result.Equals(default))` and it will infer the type for `default` automatically. To use C# 7.1 you need a recent version of Visual Studio 2017 and also set the C# version to 7.1 in your project build settings (`Advanced...`).

Comment: `Option`is perfectly suitable to be a `struct`, similar to `Nullable`. Otherwise you need to deal with nullability of an optional which is confusing.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add one more alternative to deal with value types and `FirstOrDefault`: use `Where` and cast the result to nullable type:

```
var result = Map.Where(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4)
   .Cast<(int a, int b, int c)?>().FirstOrDefault();

if (result == null)
   Console.WriteLine("Not found");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Found");
```

You can even make an extension method of it:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static T? StructFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : struct {
        return items.Where(predicate).Cast<T?>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then your original code will compile (assuming you replace `FirstOrDefault` with `StructFirstOrDefault`).

Comment: You can't probably name it `FirstOrDefault()`: overload resolution isn't done based on generic restrictions.

Comment: @xanatos you are right - it's not the best name, changed that (though it still compiles and works fine with OP example code).

Comment: Or maybe just call it `FirstOrNull`, since its purpose is to return a null value when nothing is found. +1

Answer (score 17):

In C# 7.3, it's very clean:

```
var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4);
if (result == default) {
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As written by Panagiotis you can't do it directly... You could "cheat" a little:

```
var result = Map.Where(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4).Take(1).ToArray();

if (result.Length == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
```

You take up to one element with the `Where` and put the result in an array of length 0-1.

Alternatively you could repeat the comparison:

```
var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4);

if (result.a == 4 && result.b == 4)
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
```

This second option won't work if you were looking for

```
var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 0 && w.b == 0);
```

In this case the "default" value returned by `FirstOrDefault()` *has* `a == 0` and `b == 0`.

Or you could simply create a "special" `FirstOrDefault()` that has a `out bool success` (like the various `TryParse`):

```
static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, out bool success)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (predicate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        }

        foreach (T ele in source)
        {
            if (predicate(ele))
            {
                success = true;
                return ele;
            }
        }

        success = false;
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
bool success;
var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4, out success);
```

Other possible extension method, `ToNullable<>()`

```
static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T?> ToNullable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct
    {
        return source.Cast<T?>();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var result = Map.Where(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4).ToNullable().FirstOrDefault();

if (result == null)
```

Note that `result` is a `T?`, so you'll need to do `result.Value` to use its value.

Answer (score 7):

If you are sure your data set won't include `(0, 0, 0)`, then as others have said, you can check for the default:

```
if (result.Equals(default(ValueTuple<int,int,int>))) ...
```

If that value may occur though, then you could use `First` and catch the exception when there's no match:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<(int a, int b, int c)> Map = 
        new List<(int a, int b, int c)>()
    {
        (1, 1, 2),
        (1, 2, 3),
        (2, 2, 4),
        (0, 0, 0)
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Map.First(w => w.a == 0 && w.b == 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Found");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a library, [such as my own Succinc<T> library](https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT/wiki/IEnumerableExtensions) that provide a `TryFirst` method that returns a "maybe" type of `none` if no match, or the item if matched:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<(int a, int b, int c)> Map = 
        new List<(int a, int b, int c)>()
    {
        (1, 1, 2),
        (1, 2, 3),
        (2, 2, 4),
        (0, 0, 0)
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Map.TryFirst(w => w.a == 0 && w.b == 0);
        Console.WriteLine(result.HasValue ? "Found" : "Not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add `Deconstruct` to Option, Maybe for a Go-style result, eg `var (found,value) = Map.TryFirst(...)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Hey that's a really good idea. I'll add that to the feature list for the next release. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your check could be the following:

```
if (!Map.Any(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
}
else
{
    var result = Map.First(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4);
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `result == ` in that first `if`.

Comment: your syntax is a bit off, the first if should be `if (Map.Any(...))`, but that still would not work in the desired way, it is always "Found"

Comment: if you correct the syntax on this answer it seems like the easiest solution `if (!Map.Any(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4))`

Comment: @Kritner It would work if changed to `if(!Map.Any(w => w.a == 4 && w.b == 4))` but it does iterate `Map` twice for all "Found" cases.

Comment: Ah you are right @Scrobi. It would iterate twice, which might be an issue with large datasets. If you have a smaller dataset or performance isn't a huge concern, the improved readability is worth it in my opinion.

Comment: This is probably what I would do, except I would use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, since we know the item exists.

Answer (score 6):

You need:

```
if (result.Equals(default)) Console.WriteLine(...
```

(c# > 7.1)

Answer (score 4):

ValueTuple is the underlying type used for the C#7 tuples. They cannot be null as they are value types. You can test them for default though, but that might actually be a valid value.

Also, the equality operator is not defined on ValueTuple, so you must use Equals(...).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Map.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Item1 == 4 && w.Item2 == 4);

    if (result.Equals(default(ValueTuple<int, int, int>)))
        Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how i did it with c# 7.3

```
T findme;
var tuple = list.Select((x, i) => (Item: x, Index: i)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.GetHashCode() == findme.GetHashCode());

if (tuple.Equals(default))
    return;

...
var index = tuple.Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above imply that your resulting element cannot be default(T), where T is your class/tuple.

A simple way around that is to use an approach as below:

```
var result = Map
   .Select(t => (t, IsResult:true))
   .FirstOrDefault(w => w.t.Item1 == 4 && w.t.Item2 == 4);

Console.WriteLine(result.IsResult ? "Found" : "Not found");
```

This sample uses C# 7.1 implied tuple names (and ValueTuple package for C# 7), but you can give the name to your tuple elements explicitly if required, or use a simple `Tuple<T1,T2>` instead.